# With Regex can i change urls to html image tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex

i need your help i have a list like this of urls

```
https_imgur.com/WERTYU.jpg
https_imgur.com/DRTYSF.jpg
```

i need to change them to an html img tag like this

```
<img src="https_imgur.com/WERTYU.jpg">
<img src="https_imgur.com/DRTYSF.jpg">
```

i tried to use regex but i can't find a solution

my idea is adding prefix and suffix to img url

Comment: There's no need for a regexp. Just use string concatenation or a template literal.

Comment: Or use `img = document.createElement("img"); img.src = url;`

Comment: because these urls are in wordpress post and i can just use find and replace plugin with regex

Comment: Well, that's different. You said you had a list of urls, not a block of text containing urls somewhere in it.

Comment: yes maybe i didn't explained verry well thanks 

Comment: @cineebay if this is a WP Post, then the poster should enter them with Insert Image option when making the post. If the poster did not intend them to be embedded, why do this after the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the URLs begin with `https_imgur.com`, this should find them all and replace them.

```js
let text = `Some stuff here. https_imgur.com/WERTYU.jpg
Some more stuff.
https_imgur.com/DRTYSF.jpg blah blah`;

let result = text.replace(/https_imgur\.com\/\w+\.jpg/g, '<img src="$&">');
console.log(result);
```

`$&` in the replacement string gets replaced with the match for the regexp.

Comment: yes sir it is working in js code snippet

Comment: but in the replacement string i don't know what to do

Comment: Assign it back to the `innerHTML` of the element you extracted it from.

Comment: in this example you will understand what i mean

https://regex101.com/r/W8xJuz/1

Comment: Select the JavaScript flavor to get `$&` replacement. https://regex101.com/r/5CYQ7Z/1

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var postData = $("article").html();
  var regex = /https:\/\/i.imgur\.com\/\w+\.jpg/g;
  var subst = `<img width='340' src="$&">`;
  $("article").html(postData.replace(regex, subst));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article>
  <p>Look at this.</p>
  https://i.imgur.com/qWF0ArM.jpg
  <p>Look at that.</p>
  https://i.imgur.com/qWF0ArM.jpg
  <div>https://i.imgur.com/qWF0ArM.jpg</div>
</article>
```

You will have to examine the Source of the resulting Post. Then adjust your Selector properly.